# How can I select the dropdown button with by locate the ng-repeat?

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

I want to do an automation test case to create a subnet. However, I could not select the classes that I want in the dropdown list.

Below is the code that I try to use.

```
async setSubnetClass(classes: String) {
    let val: ElementFinder;

    switch (classes) {
        case "/8":
            val = element(by.repeater('prefix in prefixes').row(0));
            // val = this.VolumeType.row(0); tryyyyyyyyyyyy
            break;
        case "/9":
            val = element(by.repeater('prefix in prefixes').row(1));
            // val = this.VolumeType.row(1);
            break;
        case "/10":
            val = element(by.repeater('prefix in prefixes').row(2));
            // val = this.VolumeType.row(1);
            break;
```

and then this is the html result of the table [html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEqcG.png)

```
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
                    <span>/&nbsp;{{selectedPrefix.id}}&nbsp;</span>
                    <span style='font-size:10px;'> 
({{selectedPrefix.usableips}} IPs)</span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
```

Please teach me and give some hint on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
async setSubnetClass(classes: String) { // pass classes = '/8' to select.

const drop = element(by.css('ul>li>a'));
await drop.sendKeys(classes);
}
```

So the above method selects `/8` from your drop down.

Hope it help you

Comment: I try use the code you provide, but when I run the test, it skip to click drop down, straight jump to next step. what is the problem there?

Comment: @BINGHAOLIM Can you share the particular html and your test script so that we can resolve the same.

Comment: yeah sure. gv me couple of time, i tried to update on the top